# Existence Of a Proper Function on a Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

In my homework I am asked to show the existence of a proper function $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and there is a hint which suggests to use a partition of unity. (here proper means that the inverse image of a compact set is compact)

I would like some help since i am not even sure where to start.
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My first answer was not correct. Let's try something else. 
Consider
a partition of unity $\left(U_{i},\varphi_{i}\right)$ subordinate
to a countable open cover of $M$ by open sets $U_{i}$ with compact
closure. Define $\theta\colon M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $\theta=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i\varphi_{i}$.
The function $\theta$ is well-defined due to the properties of partitions
of unity. We see that, for every integer $j$ :
$$
\theta^{-1}\left(\left[-j,j\right]\right)\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^{j}\left\{ x:\varphi_{i}\left(x\right)\ne0\right\} ,
$$
which has a compact closure. Hence $\theta^{-1}\left(\left[-j,j\right]\right)$
is a compact set.

Comment: How does compact closure imply that $\theta^{-1}\left(\left[-j,j\right]\right)$ is compact?

Comment: There could be points $x \in M$ where $\theta(x)=\infty$. Do you mean that only a finitely many $U_j$ intersect $U_i$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion:

Cover your manifold with a countable collection of open sets $U_1,U_2,\ldots$, such that the closure $\overline{U}_n$ is compact for every $n$ (why is this even possible?). On every $U_n$ take the constant function $f_n\equiv n.$ *Then* use a partition of unity.

Comment: That's what I had in mind! But again, how can I decide the "proper"-ity of the final function?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? What is the partition of unity doing?